# Syntax error on SQLite Alter Table with Finisar.SQLite in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to create columns through C# code.

I have tried this code:

```
string query = "Alter Table CompanyMaster ADD COLUMN CompanyType TEXT";
DbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
```

`DbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery` class code is :

```
// Class variables declared elsewhere...
private static SQLiteConnection sqlConnection;
private static SQLiteCommand sqlCmd;
private static SQLiteDataAdapter sqlAdt;

Public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string query) 
{
    try
    {
        if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlConnection.Open();

        sqlCmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandText = query;
        Thread.Sleep(5);

        return sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
        // return 0;                
    }
    finally
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

I got catch throw error

> Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'near "Alter": syntax error'

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE` command looks fine.  Something is amiss that you are not sharing.  One peculiar thing is that when I purposefully submit an error I get back the same exact text case, but you show capitalized `ALTER` in the query assignment, yet the error you show is lower case.  Have you inspected the `query` variable to ensure it contains the same exact SQL statement?  Also, it is very useful to only show relevant code, but the way you clipped the code is awkward.  At least show the full context by including the `DbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery` declaration with parameters, etc.

Comment: Dear C Perkins, Thank you for replay me , I have added two screen short , Please check it and give me some solution.

Comment: Side note: don't leave your connections open like that.  Also, that helper class you created isn't helping you.  It doesn't look like your class can pass parameters in case a query needs one.  Avoid doing things like this.  Also, get rid of that Sleep call.

Comment: @ConnectInfotech  Honestly, the screenshots do not help.  You already gave most of the code and the error, so a picture of the code and picture of the error did not add anything useful.  The only thing it helped was show the declaration of your `ExecuteNonQuery()` function, but the idea is to edit the existing code to make it more readable.  Pictures often take up too much space and distract.  (I am sharing this detail to help you improve future posts.  You will get more upvotes and more willing to help if you format your questions the best way.)

Comment: Finisar.SQLite looks [very old](http://adodotnetsqlite.sourceforge.net/) on SourceForge, last updated in 2005.  Is that the version you are using?  The ALTER TABLE statement looks just fine, so I would try another .Net sqlite implementation.

Comment: Dear All , I am using Divert.Sqlite instead of Using System.Data.Sqlite there for i got error of alter query.